# Что такое "федеративные таблицы" в Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Что такое "федеративные таблицы" в Mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень грубо говоря - ссылка на таблицу в mysq_BD1 на удалённую mysql_BD2. Пример создания:

```
CREATE TABLE `your_table` (   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `column1` enum('insert','update','delete') NOT NULL,   `column2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,   `column3` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=FEDERATED DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CONNECTION='mysql://your_user:your_password@your_host:3306/your_db/your_table';
```

Подробная инфа: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html